# Rails 4 - How to add "includes" models to a query with "joins"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I have these models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shared_cars
end
class SharedCar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :owner 
  acts_as_mappable :through => :car
end
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shared_cars
end
car Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :car_services
  has_many :cars, through: :car_services
end
```

And here's the query I am having:

```
@cars = SharedCar.joins(:car)
                 .select('COUNT(cars.id) AS grouped_cars, 
                          cars.registration,
                          cars.added_at')
                  .within(distance, origin: [lat,lng])
```

But to this query, I would need to add yet `services`. I tried

```
@cars = SharedCar.joins(:car).includes(:services)
                 .select('COUNT(cars.id) AS grouped_cars, 
                          cars.registration,
                          cars.added_at')
                  .within(distance, origin: [lat,lng])
```

The error:

```
Association named 'services' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

How to properly attached the model services into the query?

Comment: Can you please add CarService model as well?

Comment: Hi @hade, `CarService` only `belongs_to :car` and `belongs_to :service`.

Comment: You don't have any connection between SharedCar and Service, hence the error message.

Comment: there is no relationship between SharedCar & Service right ?

Answer (score 0):

Might be this helps!

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shared_cars
  has_many :car_services ##added 
  has_many :services, through: :car_services ##added
end
```

and then in your query

```
 @cars = SharedCar.joins(car: :services)
                     .select('COUNT(cars.id) AS grouped_cars, 
                              cars.registration,
                              cars.added_at')
                      .within(distance, origin: [lat,lng])
```

Comment: Thanks, @LHH. I am testing it, but the query doesn't return the fields in the `select` command.

Answer (score 0):

```
# car.rb
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shared_cars
  has_many :car_services
end

# And query with include
@cars = SharedCar.joins(:car).includes(car: {car_services: :service}).select(
  'COUNT(cars.id) AS grouped_cars,
  cars.registration,
  cars.added_at'
).within(distance, origin: [lat,lng]).references(:service)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @hade. I am testing the query, but the issue is that it returns only ID's, not the cars columns (like `grouped_cars`, `cars.registration` etc).